# get highest or different in every N rows and compare them again

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I need to get highest number every N rows and compare all of them to get a new highest number, please see the example what i mean, and I found out if I use
`data['f1'] = data['sample'].diff(1) data['f2'] = data['Close'].diff(2)`  the result in f2 will use column f1 to caculate.

```
data = pd.read_csv('M:/testdata/random_data.csv') 
data['f1'] = data['sample'].diff(1)
data['f2'] = data['sample'].diff(2)

Result:
    Sample  f1     f2
0    828    NaN    NaN
1     65 -763.0    NaN
2    703  638.0 -125.0
3    755   52.0  690.0
4    838   83.0  135.0
5     39 -799.0 -716.0
6    876  837.0   38.0
7     64 -812.0   25.0
8    506  442.0 -370.0
9    636  130.0  572.0
```

this is the result I need, column f1 is used to store highest/difference for 2 index (0 and 1), f2 column is used to store 2 index(but they skip 1,  highest for index 0 and 2)

```
    Sample  f1     f2
0    828    NaN    NaN
1     65   828    NaN          828 is largest number in 0-1
2    703   703     828        703 is largest in 1 and 2    and 828 is largest in 0 and 2
3    755   755     755       same here 755 is largest number in index 2 and 3 and index 2 and 4
4    838   838     838       838 is largest in index 3 and 4 (f1), also largest 2 and 4 (f2)
5     39   838     838
6    876   876     876
```

Comment: do you think you can describe a bit more the pattern you are looking for? is it that you want two columns: one that gets the max for indices 0-1, 1-2, 2-3,... and another for 0-2, 2-4, 4-6,...?

Comment: I want 1 column for 0 and 1 1 and 2 and other only 0 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 4, skip index 1, 2 , 3 on second column

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm still confused. I can't understand if there is a pattern for computing the max by index. Or if you really only care about indices 0-4. If so, you could just set column values with `df.loc['f1'] = df.loc[[0,1], 'Sample'].max()`. Perhaps you can update your question with the exact input and desired output you are looking for. For the desired output, just manually type the exact solution you're looking for, and really try to describe how you want the new columns to be computed.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
N = 2
df['Sample'].rolling(window=N).max()
```

Comment: it throw me an error :
KeyError: 'sample'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "M:\Python 3.7\find_high.py", line 16, in <module>
    data['f1'] = data['sample'].rolling(window=2).max()